# Apostrophe causes problems in AJAX method

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax

I have a textbox (txtDescription) where the user can type a description when an event is canceled.

The problem is when the there is an apostrophe ' with in that textbox AJAX throws an error. Without the apostrophe it works and saves fine.

I have tried using JSON.stringify but this did not work.

This is my code:

```
$("#btnCancelEvent").click(function () {
    var CencelDesc = $("#txtDescription").val();
    var user = $("#lblFullName").html();

    if (CencelDesc === "") {
        alert("Please provide a reason why this schedule event is being canceled.");
        return false;
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ScheduleOverview.aspx/CancelEvent",
            data: "{'ScheduleID': '" + ScheduleID +
                "','CentreID': '" + CentreID +
                "','CencelDesc': '" + CencelDesc + //this is where the problem occurs
                "','user': '" + user + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                swal("Information", "Schedule Event Cancelled.", "success");
                $('#CancelSchedule').modal('hide');
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Please assist how I can fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. JSON uses double quotes, not single quotes.
2. Never buld JSON strings by hand. Instead, build an object and let `JSON.stringify` handle the escaping, etc., for you.

So:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ScheduleOverview.aspx/CancelEvent",
    data: JSON.stringify({ScheduleID: ScheduleID
        ,CentreID: CentreID
        ,CencelDesc: CencelDesc
        ,user: user }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        swal("Information", "Schedule Event Cancelled.", "success");
        $('#CancelSchedule').modal('hide');
    }
});
```

---

Side note: There's no need for `dataType: "json"` in that code. You're not doing anything with the response. In fact, in general, using `dataType` is an anti-pattern. Instead, ensure that the server sends back the correct `Content-Type` header.